# Why is the preposition 'in' used in '$130,000 in hush money'?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, prepositions

> The host listed some of Trump’s worst lies and misstatements,
>   including claiming there was widespread voter fraud in the 2016
>   election and the recent revelation that he repaid his personal lawyer
>   Michael Cohen for $130,000 **in** hush money given to porn star Stephanie
>   Clifford, known as Stormy Daniels, after he’d repeatedly denied
>   knowing about the situation.
>
> ... ...
>
> “**Your base** probably might not care,” Cavuto added. “But you should. I
>   guess you’re too busy draining the swamp to ever stop and smell the
>   stink you’re creating. ... ...

I think **repaid his personal lawyer Michael Cohen for $130,000 hush money given to** without IN should be ok. Why should we add IN here? any difference?

A side question: I also wasn't sure what **your base** is referring to.

Here is [the full source](https://www.yahoo.com/news/fox-news-host-neil-cavuto-013439832.html) at Yahoo News.

Comment: "Your base" refers to his supporters that are unlikely to switch sides because of this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He paid $130,000 in bonuses.
He paid $130,000 in extra fees.

> Why should we add IN here?

Because that is the standard preposition to use.
There are more literal meanings of words, such as "on the table" or "in the room", which are clear, and then there are more idiomatic or colloquial usages of prepositions about law, money, ideas, intangible items, etc. which may not be predictable.